# conditional flows - I am stuck in- if elif else- work, I have tried some solutions that generate 1,1,1 and no -1, or 0 as required

Tags: python

just learning python. Been working on conditional flows, and got stuck here. Kindly help me out. Thanks.

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
    if ________:
        return 1
    elif ________:          
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

print greater_less_equal_5(4)
print greater_less_equal_5(5)
print greater_less_equal_5(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditionals:

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer): #Take in input
    if answer <= 5: #Check to see if it is less than or equal to 5
        return 1 #Truthy value
    else:          
        return 0 #Untruthy value

print greater_less_equal_5(4) #1
print greater_less_equal_5(5) #1
print greater_less_equal_5(6) #0
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, what you want out there, but I hope you want the function to tell you whether the number you enter is less than or greater than or equal to 5. Here is the code:

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
    if answer > 5:
        return 'Greater than 5'
    elif answer < 5:          
        return 'Less than 5'
    else:
        return 'Equal to 5'

print greater_less_equal_5(4) # Less than 5
print greater_less_equal_5(5) # Equal to 5
print greater_less_equal_5(6) # Greater than 5
```

Comment: Thank you @bharadhwaj. I now get it.